# Datastax Enterprise 5.0 cluster rebalance attempts fail

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We have a DSE 5.0 cluster of 4 machines. During data ingestion, one of these machines stored most of the data (100G) while the other three stored much less (about 15G each). I do not know why this happened and plan to investigate and probably ask in a separate question.

Now I attempt to rebalance the cluster. The only method of doing so that I am aware of is clicking `Cluster Actions` -> `Rebalance` in OpsCenter. A rebalance starts and reproducibly aborts after about 5 mins with this error:

```
Rebalance Failed: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

Some of the data is transmitted as proposed in the rebalance preview, most of it is not.

The event log:

```
Error   Rebalance failed: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out       admin
Info    Moving node xx.xx.xx.xx from token 5848419665553670365 to 2542108353485192999   NODE-04 
Info    Starting rebalance
```

What could be the reason and how do I investigate and fix it?

The cluster is deployed on 4 dedicated machines on Azure.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the data ingestion piece of this?  Are we talking a bulk load of data or normal operations?  I am just trying to get a better handle on why this might have happened in the first place.  @helmser is correct that in a normal use case with a good data model it should have evenly distributed the data.  It is still troubling that the balance job failed and that would be one to take to your account manager at DataStax to put you in touch with the tech guys on that end if it is a bug they would be able to work with you to diagnose and solve.

Comment: @mando222 - the PK is a simple SHA hash generated from the rest of the data, so I assumed well-distributed PKs. Did not get to properly analyze the actual distribution yet. Anyways the failure to rebalance does look like a bug to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to rebalance a cluster after a data load.  You probably want to dig deeper into your data model and make sure your partition key is something that will evenly distribute the data across the ring.  In this case, I'm suspecting hot spots.

Comment: Thanks helmser, this sounds entirely plausible. I have to analyze the PK distribution. However, this does not answer the question - I assume that a failure of the rebalancing function probably has other reasons as well. After all it is offered in the official UI, probably for this very situation, so I assumed it should do a better job. Do you happen do know what could be done about the timeout?